# After repartitioning, one partition now uses two drive letters

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

On the following image, the same partition gets displayed twice but with difference drive letters:

[image]

I launched **Disk Management** and I don't see the same:

[image]

How can I get rid of the duplicate drive? I tried repartitioning again but it did not help.

Partioning software used: `EaseUS Partition Master`
Operating system: `Windows 7 64bit`

I tried renaming them as well:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the partition (inside `Disk Management`). Select `Change drive letters and paths`. Make whatever changes you want.

Comment: [That worked!](http://i.imgur.com/4qS7VM6.png) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> On the following image, the same partition gets displayed twice but with difference drive letters:

One simple cause of this is the `subst` command.

```
subst
```

will tell you whether this is the case and

```
subst g: /d
```

will get rid of the extra mapping if it is.

```
subst g: d:\
```

will re-create it.

### Further reading

- [`subst`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb491006.aspx).  *Windows XP Command Reference A–Z*.  Microsoft corporation.

Comment: Hi, I think you overlooked. If you checked the drives labelled 'Storage' They both have the same storage space and label. I tried renaming one and the other gets renamed as well when I refresh.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what you were actually talking about.  Forget this, then.

Comment: No problem, @David's answer seems to have fixed it :D

Comment: Have this instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Windows 7 system. Explorer showed drive (partition) C: with both "C:" and "T:" drive letters. Change name, name changed on both, etc. I tried every suggestion I could find on the web. Even searched the registry for "T:" but found nothing.

Then, the other day, I was copying TV shows from my Freeview box's external USB drive with the "Ext2fsd" program to my Windows system:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/

While looking around the menus I saw that it had the ability to remove drive letters. I highlighted the "T:" letter and deleted it. Voila! No more "ghost" drive letter in Explorer.